# Active Directory Users homespace

Tags: windows, authentication, alfresco

I connected Alfresco with my active directory I am able to login using windows credential but how to add userspace to these windows login. I am not able to able to create new content using windows login. Also I have to login twice inorder to view the alfresco explorer page. First in browser then in alfresco login page. How to make it as single page.

Here is my global property

```
### ACtive Directory Configuration ###
authentication.chain=passthru1:passthru,ldap1:ldap,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm
passthru.authentication.sso.enabled=false
passthru.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
passthru.authentication.authenticateCIFS=false
passthru.authentication.authenticateFTP=false
passthru.authentication.servers=192.168.100.100
passthru.authentication.domain=<Netbios Domain> 
passthru.authentication.useLocalServer=false
passthru.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=sameer
passthru.authentication.connectTimeout=5000
passthru.authentication.offlineCheckInterval=300
passthru.authentication.protocolOrder=TCPIP,NETBIOS
ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://192.168.100.100:389
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
ldap.synchronization.active=true
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=uid\=sameer,cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=<administrator.privilege.account.password>
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=1000
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass=nogroup)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512))
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(& (objectclass=user)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=group)
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=modifyTimestamp
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=msExchALObjectVersion
ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=userHomesHomeFolderProvider
ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
ldap.synchronization.groupType=Nogroup
ldap.synchronization.personType=user
ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=true
cifs.enabled=false
```

Comment: Can you share your used ldap properties

Comment: @TahirMalik I added the ldap property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error kind of in your properties:
Use the **ldap.authentication.active=true** or the passthru as active subsystem

This is the reason you need to login double.
So in this case just put the

```
ldap.authentication.active=false
```

I'm not sure why you're not an admin, can you try the following:

```
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=sameer
```

or

```
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=uid\=sameer,cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com
```

Are you sure it's uid=sameer and not cn=sameer.

Comment: I edited as `ldap.authentication.active=false` but still I need to login twice

Comment: That shouldn't be needed, btw why did you use passthru? I only use passthru for Single Sign On. If you just need to login disable passthru and use the ldap authentication.

Comment: Should I just remove all the passthru statements?